# Появляющийся блок

Tags: css3, javascript, html, css

Подскажите, как создать появляющийся блок как в контакте, когда прокручиваешь страницу вниз
[image]

Обязательно ли знать php чтоб создать такой эфект или этого можно добиться с помощью css?

Comment: css+javascript.

Comment: php вообще здесь ненужен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [еще один вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/b3gZK/1/). Отличие от версий [[@Vfvtnjd](/users/4996/vfvtnjd)](/users/4996/vfvtnjd) в том, что на ВК, при клике "вниз", документ не прокручивается в самый низ документа, а мы попадаем в то место, до которого успели проскроллить и кликнуть "вверх".

P.S. Анимации на ВК я тоже не заметил, поэтому и в своем примере не стал ее тулить, хотя, если есть желание, то [можно и это соорудить](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/b3gZK/2/).

Comment: Xорошего должно быть много. + Плюсую. :)

Answer (score 3):

Читайте про якоря.
Данный эффект можно сделать при помощи javascript. Идет определение высоты прокручиваемой области(scrollTop) и идет смена видимости области с display:none на display:block.
ПХП знать не нужно,для достижения подобного эффекта.

Answer (score 2):

Слова [[@koza4ok](/users/8972/koza4ok)](/users/8972/koza4ok) в действий : ))))

```
var div = $('ваш область');
    var start = $(div).offset().top;

    $.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
        var p = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (p>start) {
                      $('блок_для_подсказки').css('display','block');
                     } 
           else $('блок_для_подсказки').css('display','none');

});
```

[Live Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/vfvtnjd/hr4Eh/1/)

**UPD**

```
Добавил и функцию "наверх"
```

[Обновленная ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/vfvtnjd/hr4Eh/2/)